# Try every column length in python

Tags: python

i have never used python before, but for a school unit i think i should learn it, 
i have a cypher text to break

```
ICBKAOREMDERAEAA
```

which is `i am a code breaker,`

to crack this by hand i had to set up a 4 x 4 grid

```
I C B K
A O R E
M D E R
A E A A
```

As you can see then just go down each column, this is what i am trying to get the code to do but for every side grid from 1 x length on input up to all possible sizes

i have managed to crack this by hand but what i am trying to do now is using python that would take the input `ICBKAOREMDERAEAA` and output every single possible combination of column sizes,

so for one column it would display

```
ICBKAOREMDERAEAA
```

for 2 columns it would halve the input and then write the result going down each column

```
ICBKAORE
MDERAEAA
```

which would output

```
IMCDBEKRAAOERAEA
```

etc,

how could i code such a think in python, i have never used it before so sorry if this is a simple question

the solution would be i think

input the text

then insert into an array and split this array each time, but how can i then code this ?

I would hope that that the algorithm would print out the answer, of the full length, and the  code would automatically have done the grid sizes, this is a basic transpotion cipher btw

Thanks to a comment on here i am using the code

```
def main():
    s = "ICBKAOREMDERAEAA"
for i in range(1, len(s) + 1): # range doesn't include upper bound
    rows = [s[x:x+i] for x in range(0, len(s), i)]
print('\n'.join(rows))
```

but do get the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "transsolve.py", line 4, in <module>
    for i in range(1, len(s) + 1): # range doesn't include upper bound
NameError: name 's' is not defined
```

Got it to compile ok ! but no output in the console :(

```
def main():
    s = "ICBKAOREMDERAEAA"
    for i in range(1, len(s) + 1): # range doesn't include upper bound
        rows = [s[x:x+i] for x in range(0, len(s), i)]
        print('\n'.join(rows))
```

i am trying to complete the output so it looks something like this

[image]

where it automatically prints out each line and have ride down each column

Comment: Could you elaborate what the algorithm should look like? Do you want a print out of the full string, then half it, then quarter it, and so on, or is it more granular than that?

Comment: I would hope that that the algorithm would print out the answer, of the full length, and the  code would automatically have done the grid sizes, this is a basic transpotion cipher btw

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a string `s`.

```
s = "ICBKAOREMDERAEAA"
```

The possible row lengths would [`range`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#range) from 1, to the length of `s`:

```
for i in range(1, len(s) + 1): # range doesn't include upper bound
```

(although you might not be interested in those above `len(s) // 2` - adjust to taste).

You can then split the string into rows based on the length using a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) and string [slicing](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-str-unicode-list-tuple-bytearray-buffer-xrange):

```
rows = [s[x:x+i] for x in range(0, len(s), i)]
```

and `print` the `rows` out by [`join`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join)ing with a line break:

```
print('\n'.join(rows))
```

or put them together into columns using [`zip`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip):

```
columns = list(zip(*rows))
```

For example, your solution (`i == 4`):

```
>>> list(zip(*[s[x:x+4] for x in range(0, len(s), 4)]))
[('I', 'A', 'M', 'A'), ('C', 'O', 'D', 'E'), 
 ('B', 'R', 'E', 'A'), ('K', 'E', 'R', 'A')]
```

Comment: Hey thanks for you comment, i have tried running it but i get the error `name s is not defined`

Comment: Unless you have a line starting `s = `, *of course* it isn't defined. But you didn't post the variable name you were using for your string.

Comment: i do have a line starting s =, i followed your example the code is above in the main question

Comment: Your indentation is wrong - the `for` loop is outside the function `main`. Indentation defines block structure in Python; getting it right is crucial.

Comment: Ah thank you very much, have managed to get it to compile now, but nothing is outputing into the console

Comment: Do you actually call the function, i.e. is `main()` in your script? This iterative commenting is not a good way to develop code; perhaps you should review an introduction to Python and get to grips with the basics.

Comment: thanks i have managed to get it working, sorry am too used to java, thanks a again, i have managed to get it working with zip and is giving me the result thanks :)